# If I use a DBSCAN algorithm with a minPts of 1 will it still run in O(nlogn) time?

Tags: c++, algorithm, performance, dbscan

I'm doing a homework problem that simplified is grouping stars into constellations given their x,y coordinates and a min distance.  Any star can be a constellation by itself.  so e.g 5 stars cant connect to each other then it will return that there are 5 constellations.

I've initially made an algorithm that checks each point with a runtime of O(n^2).  I want to make it faster and saw that a DBSCAN runs in O(nlogn) time.

My question is that if I were to use a DBSCAN the algorithm says it will run in O(nlogn) time but if my minPts is 1 (the size of my clusters) will that negate the efficiency of the DBSCAN and run in O(n^2)??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I'm concerned running time of a DBSCAN in this case depends on a calculation of neighbours, which is performed on each point, within the given distance. As you mentioned if you perform a linear scan you'd get O(n^2) in total. Nevertheless, in order to speed up a search you could use an index-based structure which searches in a O(logn) time.
Please, checkout [spatial databases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spatial_database).

Answer (score 0):

The runtime depends on epsilon being small enough so that the result sizes are small, as well as an index being able to accelerate these queries. There is no requirement on minpts, so it will work for the "degenerate" case of Single-Link clustering.

But in your case, you may simply want to use the spatial index for neighbor search directly, not go via the proxy of DBSCAN?